# Error: Input path does not exist in Hadoop - MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I've tried to run Coordinate Descent Tensor Factorization(CDTF) via Hadoop 1.2.1

The CDTF src code can get this page: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kijungs/codes/cdtf/

When I run CDTF mr(MapReduce) version algorithm, I get the following error in `Start CDTF` step after `GREEDY ROW ASSIGNMENT` step:
`ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:spark cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/spark/SALS_INPUT/example.query`.

Even an input path is existed, I don't know why this error pops up.

Is there a good solution to solve this error?

Comment: should the path be like  hdfs://<namenodehostname>:<namenodeport>/<filepath>

Comment: The port number is missing! The original path is `hdfs://master:9000/user/spark/SALS_INPUT/example.query`